# Using Google Tag Manager to insert AdSense tags in website

Tags: adsense, google-tag-manager

Hi I have a sample AdSense tag which I want to insert on my website. I already have Analytics using Tag Manager and wanted to insert another tag. I tried to use custom HTML tag but it appears on a div which has properties display:none visibility:hidden. Is it okay to implement Adsense using Tag Manager?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google_ad_client = "pub-";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
google_ad_format = "728x90_as";
google_ad_type = "text_image";
google_color_border = "FFFFFF";
google_color_bg = "0000FF";
google_color_link = "FFFFFF";
google_color_text = "000000";
google_color_url = "008000";
</script><script type="text/javascript"     src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why not, I would wrap the tag in a div and set the id to a known value and then use jQuery (or your own preference) to grab this div and insert it where you need it to be.

Use this as a starting point for your custom HTML tag:

```
<div id="my-google-adsense">
<script>
<!-- insert adsense code here -->
</script>
</div>
<script>
<!-- insert jQuery code here -->
</script>
```